# Yarn install keeps failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I'm kinda at my wits end here. I'm working on a localhost and every time I try to start the server it tells me to run yarn install, but when I try and run yarn install I get an error like this:

```
20 warnings and 6 errors generated.
20 warnings and 6 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node /Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node /Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/robertgervais/projects/bike_index/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

I've sort of been scouring stack for a while now trying to find a fix, but I'm not having any luck.

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: As of yesterday I have been experiencing the same issue with existing code that worked before yesterday.  The only thing I did was upgrade to the latest yarn (1.16.0).  I am currently looking into how to rollback to a previous version of yarn

Comment: Update:  Rolling back to yarn 1.15.2 did not fix the problem.

Comment: yarn seems to be an extremely buggy product for me too.  It's like a house of cards that falters at the slightest breeze.

Answer (score 2):

the following command will help you to get rid of the problem

```
yarn cache clean && yarn upgrade && yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.  It appears that a remote url for the version of *fsevents* that my *yarn.lock* file was referencing was giving a 404. I was able to fix this by running `yarn upgrade-interactive` and updating all my packages to the latest version.  This updated fsevent to 1.2.9 and fixed the error.

I noticed I also had the following in my console before the error message you gave:

```
$ yarn
yarn install v1.15.2
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/2] ⢀ fsevents
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/my_project_folder/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments:
Directory: /my_project_folder/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.1.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/my_project_folder/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@12.1.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and         node@12.1.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
```